# How can I add a new custom layout in Google Slides using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I would like to create a new layout using GAS, but I cannot find a method like Presentation.addLayout(), or equivalent.

Is there a straight method to achieve this or a workaround?

Comment: Have you created the custom layout ?  Or you want to add with GAS one of the predefined themes existent in the UI?

Comment: For my purpose both options are good, just I don't know the feasibility